# Manipulate session multi-array

Tags: php

I wanna to manipulate each variable inside my Array. I dont know how take a value for each array.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    /*array  name, howmuch, cost*/
    $_SESSION['ID'][] = array("Soup", 3 , 1.25);
    $_SESSION['ID'][] = array("Puos", 1 , 3.25);

    foreach ($_SESSION['ID'] as $product=>$value){

        foreach ($value as $var)
       {
           /*HERE echo ("UR product is ". name );
                  echo (howmuch);
                  echo (costo*0.40 );  */
        }
     echo ("<br>"); }
      session_destroy();   ?>
```

Grettings all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// loop with $product as a reference
foreach ($_SESSION['ID'] as &$product) {
   // 60% discount on every price
   $product[2] *= 0.4;
}
```

or

```
// use full path to each value to be changed
foreach ($_SESSION['ID'] as $key=>$product) {
   // 60% discount on every price
   $_SESSION['ID'][$key][2] *= 0.4;
}
```

Comment: great. its simple really do. I was expect [var] or something XD.

Comment: The first example looks cleaner, but sometimes you have to be careful with references. I suggest you read the [PHP manual section about them](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Comment: ok good, thank you.  it will help me, because, i didnt see about validate stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['ID'] as $value) {
    // $value will be array("Soup", 3 , 1.25), for example
    echo $value[0];
    echo $value[1];
    echo $value[2];
}
```

Comment: good, but i cant manipulate variable , just print like a String.